# How to fix TypeError _interopRequireDefault is not a function in Create React App

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to use Create React App on Codesandbox.io but I keep receiving
`TypeError _interopRequireDefault is not a function`
`import ReactDOM from "react-dom";`

Please let me know how I can fix this, thank you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After add "@babel/runtime", I fixed it

Answer (score 52):

In my case the solution was to clean `jest` cache:

```
npx jest --clearCache
```

Comment: I had this error come up randomly, without changing anything in my dependencies. Clearing the cache worked for me.

Comment: Had this error appear for no apparent reason.

Clearing the cache solved it.

Answer (score 6):

Add `@babel/runtime` to the **dependency section**. That will fix it.

Comment: I get this error after I do that:
Could not find module in path: '@babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault' relative to '/src/index.js'

Answer (score 1):

Add the below dependency in your main **package.json** file to solve that issue.

"@babel/runtime": "^7.15.4",
"metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.69.0",

Answer (score 0):

I used flowbite-react a library of tailwind and while they have given

```
import Link from 'next/link';
```

for Navbar code
just replace this with

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
```

problem would be solvd