# Babel.js: Uncaught TypeError: _interopRequireDefault is not a function

Tags: javascript, babeljs

I use the babel.js node.js API to compile react jsx and js scripts.

I have the following node.js script for example:

```js
// react_transform.js 

const fs = require("fs");

code = fs.readFileSync("./samples/sample4.js", 'utf8');

result2 = require("@babel/core").transformSync(code, {
    presets: [
        "@babel/preset-env",
        "@babel/preset-react",
    ],
    plugins: [
        "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
    ],
});

fs.writeFileSync(`./out/out4.js`, result2.code);

console.log("y.");
```

And the input file that has the jsx code is like:

```js
// sample4.js

ReactDOM.render(
    <div>
        <p>
            hoge.
        </p>
    </div>
    ,
    document.getElementById('root')
);


$(".__upvote").click(async function (e) {
    alertify.warning("You need to login.");
});
```

Without the `"@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",` line in the node.js script, when I use the script on the browser (where the output code should be located in the production), it causes an error:

```
VM496:9 Uncaught ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined
```

So, I did research and added the line. But now I started to get a new error:

```
VM830:5 Uncaught TypeError: _interopRequireDefault is not a function
```

By the way the output js file is as follows:

```js
// out4.js 

"use strict";

var _interopRequireDefault = require("@babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault");

var _regenerator = _interopRequireDefault(require("@babel/runtime/regenerator"));

var _asyncToGenerator2 = _interopRequireDefault(require("@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator"));

ReactDOM.render( /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement("div", null, /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement("p", null, "hoge.")), document.getElementById('root'));
$(".__upvote").click( /*#__PURE__*/function () {
  var _ref = (0, _asyncToGenerator2["default"])( /*#__PURE__*/_regenerator["default"].mark(function _callee(e) {
    return _regenerator["default"].wrap(function _callee$(_context) {
      while (1) {
        switch (_context.prev = _context.next) {
          case 0:
            alertify.warning("You need to login.");

          case 1:
          case "end":
            return _context.stop();
        }
      }
    }, _callee);
  }));

  return function (_x) {
    return _ref.apply(this, arguments);
  };
}());
```

So I again did research about the new error, found an SO post:

[reactjs - How to fix TypeError _interopRequireDefault is not a function in Create React App - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66327197/how-to-fix-typeerror-interoprequiredefault-is-not-a-function-in-create-react-ap)

People say:

> Add @babel/runtime to the dependency section. That will fix it.

> After add "@babel/runtime", I fixed it

So I added that "@babel/runtime" to package.json then npm install-ed. Now the package.json is like (I ommited irrelevant lines):

```json
{
    "name": "tmp",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "lodash_dev.js",
    "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
    },
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
        "@babel/runtime": "^7.17.8",
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.8.3",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx": "^7.17.3",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.17.0",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.11",
        "@babel/preset-react": "^7.16.7",
    }
}
```

Then re-run the node.js script, I get the output, I tested it on the page on the browser, however, for some reason the error still persists.

How can I fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're transforming your code with Babel, but you're not running a bundler such as esbuild or webpack.

`require()` is not a thing in the browser. The bundler's responsibility (among other things) is to take all of those `require()` calls and resolve them into real modules, and end up with one (or more) .js files that contains all of the `require()`d code and no `require()`s.

Comment: I was trying to compile server-side  (think Rails or Django) generated JavaScript that may have react or such, then pass the JS to node.js server, processing its compiling and minifying and so on, then pass back to the server, pass it to render to the client side. So if a bundler is required in addition to babel transforming here, I need to also run esbuild or webpack build to the script with its module requires, right? I think its build takes seconds, if so It's a bad idea to make users wait that much. If so, is this the only way to achieve this? I mean faster way to build for production?

Comment: Well, `esbuild` is pretty snappy at building things, so that shouldn't be that much of an issue. What is the dynamic part of your script that you need to rebuild every time? If it's "plain" enough data that you can put it in a JSON file that a static file reads, that would be easier to deal with. If it's not, then maybe you could come up with a cache system so you only rebuild-and-bundle scripts when their inputs have changed.