# .NET Core w/ React & NextJS - TypeError: _interop_require_default._ is not a function

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Have a new .NET core w/ SPA (React) project.  Want to use nextJs for some nav stuff.

Receive this compile error:

[Compile Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1yBiy.png)

that app-router-context.shared-runtime.js has this:

```
const _interop_require_default = require("@swc/helpers/_/_interop_require_default");
const _react = /*#__PURE__*/ _interop_require_default._(require("react"));
```

Here is the code from:  @swc/helpers/_/_interop_require_default

```
"use strict";

exports._ = exports._interop_require_default = _interop_require_default;
function _interop_require_default(obj) {
    return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { default: obj };
}
```

Tried researching everywhere, seen similar issues related to babel, not @swc, and tried those recommendations anyway (clearing cache, jest cache, adding babel dependencies).

Tried:  [Fix001](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66327197/how-to-fix-typeerror-interoprequiredefault-is-not-a-function-in-create-react-ap)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The exception code is full of urls that make this seem like a spam post which is why I included it in an image.

Comment: The way I read it, the code from @swc/helpers shows that it is exporting `_interop_require_default` AS `_`, not that `_` is a method of `_interop_require_default`. Have you tried `_interop_require_default(require("react"))`?

Comment: I haven't.  All those code resides within packages (node_modules) that I cannot directly manipulate.  I could try to fork them, if necessary...